# nodejs google drive api file download error with readablestream object

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to implement a function for downloading a file from the google drive using google drive api V3.
Below is my code.

```
service.files.get({
    auth: this.oauth2Client,
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: 'media'
}, {responseType: "stream"}, function (err, response) {
    console.log(response);
    response.data
    .on('end',() => {
        console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .on('data', d=> {
        progress += d.length;

        if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
            process.stdout.clearLine();
            process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
            process.stdout.write('Download ${progress} bytes');
        }
    })
    .pipe(dest);
})
```

When I run the code, I get this error.
`response.data.on is not a function`
Not just the on function, but the pipe function doesn't work either.
I already checked that response.data is the object of Readablestream.

Any ideas?

**UPDATES** 
Below is the full code for GoogleDriveSyn class.
The `getAllFilesInFolder` function works fine.

```
const path = require('path')
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');
const service = google.drive('v3');

class GoogleDriveSyn {
    constructor(auth) {
        var apiKeys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json'));
        this.oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            apiKeys['CLIENT_ID'],
            apiKeys['SECRET_ID'], 
            "http://localhost:8080" 
        );
        this.oauth2Client.credentials = auth;
        this.directory = localStorage.getItem('directory');
    }

    getAllFilesInFolder(folderId) {
        var query = '"' + folderId + '"' + ' in parents and mimeType!="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"';
        service.files.list({
            auth: this.oauth2Client,
            q: query,
            pageSize: 50,
            fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedTime, kind, createdTime, thumbnailLink, mimeType, size, webContentLink)'
        }, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                return;
              }
              console.log(response);
              return response
        })
    }

    downloadFile(fileId, filePath, fileName) {
        var fullPath = path.join(this.directory, filePath, fileName);
        var dest = fs.createWriteStream(fullPath);
        let progress = 0;

        service.files.get({
            auth: this.oauth2Client,
            fileId: fileId,
            alt: 'media'
        }, {responseType: "stream"}, function (err, response) {
            console.log(response);
            response.data
            .on('end',() => {
                console.log('Done');
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
                console.log('Error during download', err);
            })
            .on('data', d=> {
                progress += d.length;

                if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
                    process.stdout.clearLine();
                    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
                    process.stdout.write('Download ${progress} bytes');
                }
            })
            .pipe(dest);
        })
    }
}

module.exports = GoogleDriveSyn;
```

Also, below is the log of response inside `downloadFile` function.

```
{config: {…}, data: ReadableStream, headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: ""}
config: {url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1zcxy0wWsPuWINMY8FP_bjR4nrnj6t8eD?alt=media", method: "GET", responseType: "stream", headers: {…}, paramsSerializer: ƒ, …}
data: ReadableStream {locked: false}
headers: {alt-svc: "h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,…3"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"", cache-control: "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate", content-disposition: "attachment", content-length: "12", content-type: "text/plain", …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can we think that your script for authorizing works for downloading the files from Google Drive? 2. Can I ask you about the file type you want to download. Because in your script, the files except for Google Docs can be downloaded. When you want to download the Google Docs files, it is required to change the method for downloading them.

Comment: Without knowing what `service.files.get` it is a bit difficult to answer but I would assume that `response` is the object with the `on` method, i.e. change `response.data.on(..)` to `response.on(..)`.

Comment: This might be an authorization issue; hence the reason of not receiving a response. You should check for an error before doing anything.

Comment: @Morfinismo : the authorization is fine. I'm getting response with status code 200.

Comment: @Tanaike : 1. Yes. authorizing works for downloading files. 2. I'm testing with a text file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, the modified script works. But if that didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to download a text file from the Google Drive.
- Your script for authorizing works fine. So `this.oauth2Client` can be used for downloading the file.

#### Modification points:

- In my environment, I confirmed that your script worked. But in your question, you say the error of `response.data.on is not a function` occurs. So in this modification, `downloadFile` was modified as follows.
- **At first, please confirm the version of googleapis for Node.js you are using. In this case, please use the latest version of googleapis for Node.js. In the current stage, the latest version is `googleapis@55.0.0`.**

  - If you use the old one, I thought that the reason of your issue might be this.
- In your script, `'Download ${progress} bytes'` is not correct. In this case, please use it as the template literal. By this, the progress information can be seen.

#### Modified script:

```
downloadFile(fileId, filePath, fileName) {
  var fullPath = path.join(this.directory, filePath, fileName);
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream(fullPath);
  let progress = 0;
  return drive.files
    .get(
      { auth: this.oauth2Client, fileId: fileId, alt: "media" },
      { responseType: "stream" }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        response.data
          .on("end", () => {
            resolve("\nDone");
          })
          .on("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
          })
          .on("data", (d) => {
            progress += d.length;
            if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
              process.stdout.clearLine();
              process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
              process.stdout.write(`Download ${progress} bytes`);
            }
          })
          .pipe(dest);
      });
    });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Drive v3 API Samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/drive)

  - You can see the sample script at `download.js`.